# Setup Azure DevOps agent with user account

Tags: azure-devops

I tried to setup an Azure Devops agent with my username@domain.com and my current windows login password in Powershell according to the Azure introduction (PS >.\config.cmd).
I already could successful setup and run in interactive mode and start from PC side and from Azure web site manually, as well.

To go ahead to the final solution I then wanted to setup the agent as a service.
I tried to use the version with my username, userdomain and password as mentioned above.
But the setup procedure in Powershell does not accept my windows login password though I use this every day for login procedures to several company software.

What could be the reason?
Is a different password meant ... I dont know what else I could type in :D

I can not use the network service since then my python application on my PC will not run correctly .. so I intended to use my user account for the service.
Any idea?
Thx a lot for any helpful hint :)